# Find players who have all "win", "draw" and "loss" results

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
player1_id | score1 | score2 | player2_id
-----------+--------+--------+-----------
         1 |      1 |      1 |          2
         3 |      1 |      1 |          1
        11 |      1 |      0 |         20
         5 |      1 |      1 |         55
       200 |      1 |      2 |         11
        17 |      1 |      1 |          7
        11 |      1 |      3 |          4
        11 |      1 |      1 |        100
        20 |      1 |      1 |          2
        20 |      2 |      1 |         33
```

Player have "win", "draw" or "loss" results according  to score1 and score2.  I need find players, who have all "win", "draw" and "loss" results. In this case, players 11 and 20.

I am stuck here, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add more data? E.g. table name, what sql you tried, and how can we detect "win", "draw" and "loss" results in this table.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: No homework questions to be posted. Show us what you have tried till now.

Comment: *I need find players, who have all "win", "draw" and "loss" results.* -- do you mean, you need to find players, who have at least one for each of "win", "draw" and "loss"?

Comment: pozs Yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select p from (
    select player1_id as p, case when score1>score2 then 'W' when score1=score2 then 'D' when score1<score2 then 'L' end as res from your_table
    union all
    select player2_id as p, case when score1>score2 then 'L' when score1=score2 then 'D' when score1<score2 then 'W' end as res from your_table
) t
group by p
having count( distinct res ) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all the players into one column, along with the scores or an indicator of the groups that you want:

```
select p1
from ((select player1_id as p1, player2_id as p2, score1 as s1, score2 as s2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select player2_id as p1, player1_id as p2, score2 as s1, score1 as s2
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by p1
having sum( (s1 > s2)::int) > 0 and
       sum( (s1 = s2)::int) > 0 and
       sum( (s1 < s2)::int) > 0;
```